# Including Lilypond in LaTeX

Tags: lilypond

It states [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/usage/latex), that i have to include Lilypond into LaTeX like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{lilypond}
\relative c'' {
\time 4/4

< a e' a >2 
< a e' a >4
< a e' a >8
< a e' a >8 

} 
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

But this is not working, as command `\begin{lilypond}` isn't reckognized, so i end up with nothing. Do i have to include any packages or what? That tutorial is so sloppy...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .tex file with the lilipond environments must be compiled with `lilipond-book`, for example with the command
`lilypond-book -f latex --psfonts --output OUTPUT TEX_FILE.tex`

This is explained in a different part of the lilipond documentation: 
http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond-program/Invoking-lilypond_002dbook#Invoking-lilypond_002dbook

Comment: I have been searching for _lilypond.sty_ on CTAN, but it isn't there. Only context is there.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem. I'll edit my answer, since it was wrong